# Trying to approve, deny, or delete multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a list of users that I would like to be able to either approve, deny, or delete. I don't want to do one by one, because it would be too much work. [image: My list of users]

I have the following code for the approve, deny, and delete columns:

```html
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$row['user_id'].'">
    <td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#DFF0D8;">
      <input type="radio" name="approve[]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#FCF8E3;">
      <input type="radio" name="approve[]" value="0">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#FCDEDE;">
      <input type="radio" name="approve[]" value="3">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to set the "approved" column in the table "users" in MySQL to 1 if it is approved and to keep it to 0 if it is denied. If "delete" is chosen, then I want to be able to delete that row of data. How can I do this for a list of users? If it was just one by one it would be easy, but I don't know how to do it for multiple users.

I thought of looping through the "approve" array, but I can't change the values in the database because I don't know how to match this to a user_id.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see two possible paths here: either have a new set of radios for each user with a new `name`, or think of this as three multi-choice `select`s, approve, deny, delete, and delegate having a better front-end display of that to client-side JS.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichSchwarz Schwwarz! I am a newbie at this stuff... would it be too much of a bother if I ask you to explain this a little bit in more detail? I am just not sure how to go about either of those options.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample for multi delete:

index.php

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<form method="post" action="delete.php" >
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">

                            <strong>Check the radion Button and click the Delete button to Delete Data</strong>
                        </div><thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>FirstName</th>
                                <th>LastName</th>
                                <th>MiddleName</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php 
                        $query=mysql_query("select * from member")or die(mysql_error());
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        $id=$row['member_id'];
                        ?>

                                    <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                    </td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['lastname'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['middlename'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                            </tr>

                              <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" name="delete">
```

delete.php

```
<?php 
include('dbcon.php');
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
$id=$_POST['selector'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM member where member_id='$id[$i]'");}
header("location: index.php"); } ?>
```

Comment: Please don't suggest deprecated libraries (**`mysql_*`** in this instance) as an alternative as they are insecure/obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple users you just need to add a dimension to all your form variable names:

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#DFF0D8;">
      <input type="radio" name="approve[<?= $row['user_id'] ?>]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#FCF8E3;">
      <input type="radio" name="approve[<?= $row['user_id'] ?>]" value="0">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding:20px; background-color:#FCDEDE;">
      <input type="radio" name="approve[<?= $row['user_id'] ?>]" value="3">
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the form is posted you will receive something like this:

```
approve[123]=1&approve[456]=2&...
```

This will turn `$_POST['approve']` into an array:

```
array(
    123 => 1
    456 => 2
);
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Ja͢ck for your answer. What would be 123? and would 1 be the option chosen(approve, deny, delete)?